# How to pass value from class to class - Python

Tags: python, class

I am trying to pass a value from one function in a class to another function in a class. Below is some simplified code of what I'm trying to achieve.

```py
class test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.differentvalue = 0
    def set(self, value):
        print(value)
        self.differentvalue = value #this is not the same value as defined above - i.e. this is a new variable created in foo class i believe

class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        test.set(self, 5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo()
```

I do not want `__init__` to be called so `test().set(5)` is not an option.

Cheers,
Sean

Comment: This sounds strongly like an XY problem. What is the real world problem you are trying to solve? The only way to set values without calling `__init__` is to set it on the class, and not on the instance, which is probably not what you want (but is hard to tell without more info)

Comment: Hi Keozon, I am trying to call only the instance `set` from the class `foo`. In other words, I want `foo` to call `set`. `__init__` in `test` should only be called once, no matter how many times `set` is called.

Comment: do you want your change to ```differentvalue``` to be class-wide? Keep in mind the difference between a class and an instance of a class.

Comment: Hey Tom, yes I would like to be able to access `differentvalue` from anywhere in `test`

Comment: @Keozon while I agree this is major code smell, you can set values on instances anywhere in python, in any method or outside the class as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options

Option #1, best option if you need to keep a different context for differtvalue for each instance of Test

```py
class Test:

    def __init__(self):
        self.differentvalue = 0

    def set(self, value):
        self.differentvalue = value

class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        test = Test()
        test.set(5)
```

Option #2, best if you need to keep the latest value for differentvalue across all Test classes

```py
class Test:

    __DIFFERENTVALUE = 0

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def set(value):
        Test.__DIFFERENTVALUE = value

class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        Test.set(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define a class variable with a value of `None`, then upon calling the setter for the first time, assign a value to it. Further calls to the setter will not change the value.

In the following example, an `__init__` method is not required in `Test`.

```
class Test:

    differentvalue = None

    @classmethod
    def set(cls, value):
        if value is not None and Test.differentvalue is None:
            Test.differentvalue = value

class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        Test.set(5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo()
    print(Test.differentvalue)
    Test.set(12)
    print(Test.differentvalue)
```

**output:**

```
5
5   # the value did not change
```